# create version.txt file in project dir via build.gradle task

Tags: git, file, gradle, build.gradle, versioning

Apologies in advance for my ignorance. I'm very new to gradle.

My is goal is to have some task in my build.gradle file, wherein a file 'version.txt' is created in my project directory whenever I run the `gradle` terminal command in my project root. This 'version.txt' file needs to contain version metadata of the build, such as:

`Version: 1.0
Revision: 1z7g30jFHYjl42L9fh0pqzmsQkF
Buildtime: 2016-06-14 07:16:37 EST
Application-name: foobarbaz app`

(^Revision would be the git commit hash of the HEAD)

I've tried to reuse snippets from the following resources, but to no avail, possibly because these resources are out of date:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2015/04/gradle-goodness-use-git-commit-id-in.html
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/10/gradle-goodness-add-incremental-build.html

I'm using gradle version 2.14 (which is the latest version).

Any help and/or insight would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Also, to automate the call at each build, with Gradle: ``compileJava {
    dependsOn versionTxt
}``

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The example you're referring to is almost correct. With a couple of minor tweaks it works as expected:

```groovy
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit

plugins {
    id "org.ajoberstar.grgit" version "1.7.2"
}

version = 1.0

task versionTxt()  {
    doLast {
        new File(projectDir, "version.txt").text = """
Version: $version
Revision: ${grgit.head().abbreviatedId}
Buildtime: ${new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())}
Application-name: foobarbaz app
"""
    }
}
```

Run `gradle versionTxt` to get the desired output.

Comment: This worked as expected. The example I was referring to was indeed almost correct. Thanks again!

Comment: Minor tweaks: the leftShift is deprecated and should be replaced with `doLast` inner closure. Also, you can shorten the file creation to a one-liner `new File(filename).text = "blah"`

Comment: You could use `file(...).text = ...` instead of `new File(...).text = ...`.

Comment: @deamon but only in newer Gradle versions... e.g. 2.14 (used by ForgeGradle) doesn't have the file method

Comment: I updated the version (to the latest stable) and the code.

Comment: In Kotlin based DSL, it would be `file("filePath").writeText("file content")`