# Getting version and build info with gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have gradle-based Groovy project; it's application. Gradle version is 4.1.

```
group 'com.vendor.path'
version '0.1-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'
```

I want to extract version and buildtime into *.resources for use them at runtime (About box, logs).

How may I got it without Git?
Is Git versioning plugin more suitable for my question?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:filter(java.util.Map,%20java.lang.Class), https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:expand(java.util.Map), https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#filterOnCopy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275583/create-version-txt-file-in-project-dir-via-build-gradle-task

Comment: Cool, I'll close this question, have fun!