# The DefaultSourceDirectorySet constructor has been deprecated. How to use the ObjectFactory service?

Tags: gradle

I recently updated to gradle version 5.0-rc-4, and when running `./gradlew assemble` (or any other task) I now get the following message:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
```

When I use `./gradlew assemble --warning-mode all` I get:

```
> Configure project :
The DefaultSourceDirectorySet constructor has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0. Please use the ObjectFactory service to create instances of SourceDirectorySet instead.
```

But in the following `build.gradle` I don't see where I'm using any `DefaultSourceDirectorySet`, so what is this warning about, and what would I need to change to be compatible with Gradle 6.0?

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.10'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}
```

*Related*

I found [create version.txt file in project dir via build.gradle task(gradle 5.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267959/create-version-txt-file-in-project-dir-via-build-gradle-taskgradle-5-0) but I don't have constructs like that so I don't know how it would apply.

I found this deprecation mentioned in the release notes at https://docs.gradle.org/5.0-milestone-1/release-notes.html but they say

> In this release of Gradle, the ObjectFactory service, which is part of the public API, now includes a method to create SourceDirectorySet instances. Plugins can now use this method instead of the internal types.

but I don't see how.

I also found the `SourceDirectorySet` interface at https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html but I don't see how to use it.

Template repository: https://github.com/PHPirates/kotlin-template-project

Comment: I'm guessing that this deprecation message comes from a plugin you are using. In this case, it is probably coming from the kotlin plugin.

Comment: @mkobit That would make sense. In that case I trust they'll solve it in time. I'll make sure this question is answered when the warning has disappeared, or when somebody finds out where the warning comes from.

Comment: This seems relevant – https://discuss.gradle.org/t/the-defaultsourcedirectoryset-constructor-has-been-deprecated/29610

Comment: @ThomasDavidBaker Yes that seems to be it, thanks for the link!

Comment: Looks like this has been reported to the Kotlin team: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26808

Comment: @Javaru I see, three months ago... thanks for the link! Will add it to the current answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Update 2019-01-23** Five minutes ago, kotlin 1.3.20 was [released](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.3.20) and also updated in the [Gradle repository](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm) so this issue should be solved by updating the Kotlin Gradle plugin to 1.3.20.

**Update 2019-01-11** The target version in [Youtrack issue KT-26808](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26808) has just been updated to 1.3.20. You can view the latest released version in the Gradle repositories [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm), but at the moment there are still a lot of [open issues for 1.3.20](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues?q=Target%20versions:%201.3.20%20State:%20Open%20).

**Update 2018-12-17** The deprecation warning is fixed in commit https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/67e82a54e5ee529116e881953f93a4c8f216e33a, the Youtrack issue is closed. Now waiting for a [release](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm) to roll out.

As @Javaru [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461821/the-defaultsourcedirectoryset-constructor-has-been-deprecated-how-to-use-the-ob/53669229#comment94285145_53461821), this has already been reported (in september 2018) at [Youtrack issue KT-26808](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26808).

Using information from [Lance's comment](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/the-defaultsourcedirectoryset-constructor-has-been-deprecated/29610/7) in the link that [Thomas David Baker pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461821/the-defaultsourcedirectoryset-constructor-has-been-deprecated-how-to-use-the-ob#comment94016269_53461821):

### Answer:

If you get this warning while you are not using `DefaultSourceDirectorySet` directly, this is probably coming from a Gradle plugin you use. You could check this using the `--warning-mode all --stacktrace` flags for the Gradle build, so like `./gradlew assemble --warning-mode all --stacktrace`.

In this particular case it's the Kotlin Gradle Plugin, they use it at [DefaultKotlinSourceSet.kt#L140-L155](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/a44d70e79d06a5133b86470c749cc2d0bf870053/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/sources/DefaultKotlinSourceSet.kt#L140-L155):

```
private val createDefaultSourceDirectorySet: (name: String?, resolver: FileResolver?) -> SourceDirectorySet = run {
    val klass = DefaultSourceDirectorySet::class.java
    val defaultConstructor = klass.constructorOrNull(String::class.java, FileResolver::class.java)

    if (defaultConstructor != null && defaultConstructor.getAnnotation(java.lang.Deprecated::class.java) == null) {
        // TODO: drop when gradle < 2.12 are obsolete
        { name, resolver -> defaultConstructor.newInstance(name, resolver) }
    } else {
        // (code omitted)
    }
}
```

We can trust that they will resolve the issue in time, so don't worry about the warning.

Comment: Thanks for keeping the issue up to date. Maybe a link at the top to the issue itself [KT-26808](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-26808) would be nice too. However it seems that there are still a lot of open tickets: [Open tasks for 1.3.20](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues?q=Target%20versions:%201.3.20%20State:%20Open%20).

Comment: @rekire You're welcome! Agree, I just added an extra link so it is less hidden. Thanks for the second link, I'm not familiar with the release scheduling but that seems like a lot of issues!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the search too, but I tried the search and I have a bug report for 1.3.30  so I was interested for the outstanding work